# How to subset data in SAS?

Tags: loops, sas, dataset, subset

I have a dataset as follows:

```
1 16.60 4923 1198 29663 1927 Davis California
2 10.09 3055 883 30282 1989 Palo Alto California 
3 9.61 5128 1096 53388 2489 Boulder Colorado 
4 8.85 4674 1210 52815 2600 Berkeley California 
5 7.28 4793 1051 65794 3408 Eugene Oregon 
6 6.64 5112 1215 76972 3579 Fort Collins Colorado 
7 6.59 3125 1608 47451 2701 Santa Barbara California 
8 6.41 2433 1078 37968 2671 Chico California
```

Where the variables are `bike_share`, `total_biker`, `error_biker`, `total_worker`, `error_worker`, `city`, `state`, respectively. For this dataset, I want to calculate the average% of Californians that ride bikes to work (i.e, I want to sum up the `total_biker` that are from `state` California and divide that number by sum of `total_worker`).

First I want to identify the people who are Californians, so I wrote the following `do` loop to find the number of `total_bike` that are from California. 
[image]
    total_bike_cali=0;
    do i=1 to 8; 
    if state="California" then total_bike_cali=total_bike_cali+total_bike;
    else total_bike_cali=0; 
    end;
    proc print;
    run;

However this gave me an error

```
 Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

For pretty much every line of the loop. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: SAS handles the row-wise iteration for you.  You're thinking like a matrix language.  You're also not in a data step in that code, hence none of the code is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this a number of ways.  Here are two.

```
proc sql;
select sum(total_biker)/sum(total_worker) 
  from your_data
  where state='California';
quit;
```

or

```
data have;
length city state $20;
input bike_share total_biker error_biker total_worker error_worker city $ state $;
datalines;
16.60 4923 1198 29663 1927 Davis California
10.09 3055 883 30282 1989 Palo Alto California 
9.61 5128 1096 53388 2489 Boulder Colorado 
8.85 4674 1210 52815 2600 Berkeley California 
7.28 4793 1051 65794 3408 Eugene Oregon 
6.64 5112 1215 76972 3579 Fort Collins Colorado 
6.59 3125 1608 47451 2701 Santa Barbara California 
6.41 2433 1078 37968 2671 Chico California
;;;;
run;

data want;
set have end=eof;
if state='California' then do;
  total_worker_cali+total_worker;
  total_biker_cali+total_biker;
  put _all_;
end;
if eof then do;
  total_cali_pct = total_biker_cali/total_worker_cali;
  output;
end;
run;
```

You could also set the data up so that `PROC MEANS` or `PROC TABULATE` could do the table for you; that would be the way to do it if you wanted each state, not just one specific one.

Here's an example of doing it with `PROC MEANS`.  This isn't quite as accurate, because `bike_share` is rounded; if you recalculate it from the original variables it will be more accurate.

```
proc means data=have;
class state;
weight total_worker;
var bike_share;
run;
```

Here you use `total_worker` as the weight, to bring the summarized dataset back to looking like an unsummarized dataset with one row per worker.

Comment: thank you for the response. For the second approach, do I need to initialize the variables `total_worker_cali` and `total_biker_cali`? Or else they wouldn't be defined right?

Comment: Nope, they're fine as is.  The + operator used that way will both automatically retain them, and automatically initialize set them correctly.  This is only true since I'm using it as the increment operator, not after an equals sign.

Comment: I see. Hmm, something's not quite working right. I get the note that there's a division by 0: `eof=1 Bike_Share_Commuters=6.41 Total_Bike=2433 Margin_Error_Biker=1078 Total_Workers=37968
Margin_Error_Worker=2671 city=Chico state=California total_worker_cali=0 total_biker_cali=0
total_cali_pct=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=8
`

Comment: Did you fix the variable name to match yours properly?

Comment: Yes, I did. Here's what I had `data want;
set biker_data end=eof;
if state='California' then do;
  total_worker_cali+Total_Workers;
  total_biker_cali+Total_Bike;
end;
if eof then do;
  total_cali_pct = total_biker_cali/total_worker_cali;
  output;
end;
run;`

Comment: I added a screenshot of the dataset `biker_data` I'm using. Sorry for the confusion since the variable names did not match what I had originally specified in the problem.

Comment: I wonder if you have formatted values, and `California` is really a number with a character format?  If so you need to use the number underlying it, not the formatted value, or use `vvalue(state)` to get the formatted value.  The code above (I added the `have` dataset for clarity) works fine.